# CloudFront closes connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-cloudfront

We have a ASP.Net MVC 3 legacy CMS application. This application serves resized images to CloudFront as a Custom Origin. 
Most requests are fine and either the cache is hit or the image can be retrieved from the CMS application. It has come to our attention that on some of the request the following `HttpException` occurs:

```
The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD.
```

This error occurs while the server is trying to flush the output stream.

The following headers are being sent before the output stream is flushed:

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 142475
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=banner.jpg
```

The issue is not bound to the file. It seems to randomly occur on all kinds of files and is also size independent.

I already tried searching for this issue and couldn't find anything specific on it. I just wanted to check if anyone has some experience with these issues on CloudFront.

Comment: see this link maybe it could help.. http://blog.whitesites.com/fixing-The-remote-host-closed-the-connection-The-error-code-is-0x80070057__633882307305519259_blog.htm

Comment: The url is not reachable for me, it says: The connection time out. Do you have another post or article discussing this issue?

Comment: sorry, I manage to reach it without any problems.. it seemed to me the best post i've seen about your issue, but I think that if you search for it on the web maybe you find better

Comment: More information might be useful, here: are you actually experiencing any problems with the site from a user perspective?  Can you correlate these errors with entries in the CloudFront logs? What do the CloudFront logs show?  Are these requests running for several seconds on your side before returning the response to CloudFront, or are they fast?